# two images on top of each other

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to create a new table (with `ngRepeat`) when I receive new data via Ajax.
Part of each table row is an image.

Under certain conditions I want to display an overlay image (which is mostly transparent except for an icon indicating the condition) right on top of the main image.

I am currently using a js solution by assigning a handler to the load event of the image (obtaining the position of main image and setting overlay image to the same position).
That works but I have to use $apply to make sure all images are constructed in the DOM before I can attach the load event.

I was wondering if there is a pure html/css solution to the problem?
Simply make sure the overlay image is always in the exact same position as the main image.
The I can simply bind `ngShow` to the condition and avoid all js tricks.

ETA:
here's the relevant code snippet from the table (within the ngRepeat):

```
<div class="movie-cover">
    <img class="movie-image" ng-src="{{movie.ImageUrl}}" onerror="this.src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/titleimages/NoImage.jpg")'" />
    <img class="selected-image dontshow" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Selected.png")" data-hh-id="{{movie.ID}}" />
    <a class="movie-link" href="{{movie.ImdbUrl}}" target="_blank">IMDb</a>
</div>
```

I want the image with the class '`selected-image`' on top of the other one.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try:

```
.movie-cover {position:relative;width:400px;height:400px;}
.movie-cover img {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
```

Comment: That works. I am still having problems sometimes with css positioning but your combination of relative and absolute works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, one idea is that you can load first image as a cover background to a div and load second image inside that div with height:100%.

**Edit**

I realise this would also require js as you are loading it via ajax. 
Second idea is that you can place both images inside same div with height 100% with absolute position and top, left set to 0 relative to parent div?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. However, the image link is dynamic and part of the json data I receive. Is your suggestion still possible with dynamic links?

Comment: It should work fine as the second option is pure css. But I must ask, does overlay image has same dimensions as the main image ? And can you please share a screenshot to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Harald I am sorry but my answer was same, I didn't know you just wanted the code.

Comment: I realize your code was virtually the same but given my problems with css positioning the other answer helped me quicker. I did upvote your answer tho.